# Raspberry Pi 3: own Wi-Fi network (without internet)

Tags: wifi, hotspot, minibian

Here I explain better what I would like to do with the Pi.

The Raspberry 3 Pi has Minibian installed and serves as a controller for a robot that needs the Wi-Fi connection to work properly.

Up to now I am using it in my house, so I know exactly the SSID and the password of the network, therefore I have set them as a scheme in the network interfaces file so that the Pi can connect to them after the boot.

The problem is that if I want to use the Raspberry in other places, I need to insert manually the new scheme containing the SSID and the password of the new network. So, what I want to do is that if the Pi doesn't find any known network, it builds its own Wi-Fi network (without being connected to internet), so that I can connect to it saying which is the SSID, I want it to connect to, and the related password.

Is it possible to do? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Pethaps this may help
https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/

Answer (score 4):

You can create an access point without Internet connection through the [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) command line tool.

> Features
>
> Internet sharing methods: NATed or Bridged or None (no Internet sharing).

Install `create_ap`:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap.git
cd create_ap
make install
```

> AP without Internet sharing:

```
create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

Project moved to [linux-wifi-hotspot](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot): A GUI interface which use `create_ap` as CLI. The above above command is valid.

```
git clone https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot
cd linux-wifi-hotspot
make
wihotspot
```

Comment: I get `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill` to this, will try workarounds like from https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146198 but if you have some consistent reply to this, please share

Comment: yeap, after running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade &` and then making sure that WiFi is enabled but Pi is not connected to a WiFi network and also running `create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase --daemon` (all through ethernet) I was able to connect to the new network (SSID of MyAccessPoint) and to SSH (via the static IP)

Comment: yeap, I know, but that's not my next target, next target is to launch `create_ap` on system start so that I can always connect to R Pi via WiFi (without ethernet or additional monitor). My current plan is to explore `systemd` for that purpose

Comment: @YakovL to launch the daemon at boot time use `sudo systemctl enable create_ap`

Comment: Hm, I failed to find an explanation: does `sudo systemctl enable create_ap` makes `create_ap` be launched with the latest used params? In other words if I use `sudo systemctl enable create_ap` after `create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase` it will remember those params? Or should I use those in an opposite order? What `sudo systemctl enable create_ap` actually does?

Comment: @YakovL the above command will enable the daemon at boot , If you need to start the AP at boot you can create a cron job , `sudo crontab -e` then add the command `@reboot create_ap wlan0 wlan0 AP passwd`

Comment: Thanks, in the end I've succeeded with `@reboot /path/to/create_ap.sh` in crontab where the latter has only one command, namely `create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase --daemon` (after the `#!/bin/bash` line), but failed to make this work without a separate script: for instance, neither `@reboot create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase --daemon` nor `@reboot create_ap -n wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase --daemon &` worked for me

Comment: PS I've made a separate question for this bit: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/77130/64243