# crontab entry with parameters?

Tags: cron

My goal was to make my Pi create its own WiFi on start so that I can connect to it wirelessly.

I have succeeded by creating a crontab entry (using `sudo crontab -e`):

```
@reboot /path/to/create_ap.sh &
```

where `create_ap.sh` is a script launching `create_ap`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo create_ap -n wlan0 MySSID MyPass --daemon
```

However, I've failed to do this without an additional script: both

```
@reboot create_ap -n wlan0 MySSID MyPass --daemon
```

and

```
@reboot create_ap -n wlan0 MySSID MyPass --daemon &
```

didn't work as expected (I've also tried to add full path, `/usr/bin/create_ap` like suggested in comments but that didn't help).

So *does crontab allow parameters after the command?* (I suspect that only `@reboot create_ap` bit works in practice, but failed to google that) Or is there some other problem with these lines in crontab and I can adjust them so that an external script is not needed?

Comment: Does using the full path to `create_ap` in your crontab work? (I believe the path is `/usr/bin/create_ap`). Does your crontab change the `PATH` variable in any other way?

Comment: @Aurora0001 thanks, `which create_ap` says `/usb/bin/create_ap` and I've tried full path in crontab but that didn't help

Comment: Is this a user crontab, or your system crontab? If it's a user crontab (created with ```crontab -e```) one difference is that the command kicks off as your user, whereas your script includes ```sudo``` to execute the command as root. This should go into a system crontab to execute as root on startup.

Comment: @bobstro I only used `sudo crontab -e` so that's root crontab, I guess. Will add this to the question

Comment: You've specified a path to the script in your working example, but not a path the the ```create_ap``` script in the non-working entries. Try prepending a path to ```create_ap```. Check logs or email for errors.

Comment: @bobstro I've already tried that like Aurora0001 has suggested, even edited the question ("I've also tried to add full path, `/usr/bin/create_ap` like suggested in comments but that didn't help"). Though, I'm not sure what logs to check and how to check email yet.

Comment: As an alternative to crontab, you might be interested in: https://blog.usedbytes.com/2019/11/run-at-startup-without-rc.local/

Comment: Is this a serious question - or a game you are playing? I ask because: a) the question is nearly 3 years old, and b) starting WiFi AP is something the system will do without a `cron` job. I'd suggest you delete this question, and start over.

Comment: @Seamus it was a serious question back than, why would I delete it after 3 years later? I got 4 upvotes (I suspect you're the one who downvoted) so this is probably an issue others have. *starting WiFi AP is something the system will do without a `cron` job* – please elaborate, this didn't happen by itself in my case.

Comment: @ukBaz thanks for the suggestion, currently that project of mine is "archived" but I may return to it and will try your suggestion in that case

Comment: YakovL: Yes, I downvoted your question. Downvoting means I feel it "shows no research effort", or "is not useful". No - it doesn't happen by itself; it's a computer, not a magic lamp. Did you try an Internet search for an answer to your question? A search on ["raspberry pi wifi"](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=raspberry+pi+wifi&ia=web) returns this item titled ["Setting up a wireless LAN via the command line"](https://is.gd/lmwkQS). It's from the "official" documentation - one of thousands of results returned. Try it. If it doesn't work for you, consider editing your question to let us know.

Comment: @Seamus oh, now I finally see what bothers you, I've asked about `cron` on an example that's actually easier solved without `cron`. That may be true, I can't really say what I've googled back than and why I tried `cron` and not some other method. However, the question is about `cron` and not about setting a wireless connection because I wanted to know more about `cron`. I've searched a bit but haven't found why what I tried didn't work, so I've asked here. No, I don't have another, more pressing issue regarding `cron` at hand to rewrite this question, sorry.

Comment: Yes - it is true... FWIW, I just checked, and in a [search using the word `cron`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=cron) there are 1,003 Q&A here on RPi SE. You might also look at `systemd` for starting things. An entire world of help is out there - all for the cost of a search.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `.sh` script calls `sudo` before `create_ap`. Either run the crontab entry as root, or prepend the `sudo`. So try `@reboot sudo /usr/bin/create_ap -n wlan0 MySSID MyPass --daemon`

Comment: I used `sudo crontab -e` which means I used the first option, right? I've read also that the second option is not a proper approach: https://askubuntu.com/a/173930/532531 (but actually I've already tried the line you proposed as well)

Comment: Yes, `sudo crontab -e` works if you want to run the crontab entry as root directly. Considering the second option, you can mitigate that risk from the link by putting `pi ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/create_ap` in `/etc/sudoers.d/pi`.

Comment: Reading https://github.com/oblique/create_ap also gives the alternative to start it from `systemd` (also check https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/4).